# object as exit() parameter

Tags: php, fuelphp

Is this even valid? Because it's working.

```
if(empty($query)) {
    exit(View::forge('error', $data));
    //View::forge('error', $data) = object
}
```

According to PHP manual [exit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) should only accept "string" or "int" as parameter.

So I tried:

```
if(empty($query)) {
    return View::forge('error', $data);  //will not display
}

    return View::forge('default', $data);  //displays
```

But it seems it ignores it and displays the default template, so I tried combining it with exit:

```
if(empty($query)) {
    return View::forge('error', $data);  //will not display
    exit;
}

return View::forge('default', $data);  //displays
```

But still the same result, what I want to know that is exit($obj) valid in fuelphp? Because it seems it's working.

What I want to do is if query is empty page would display error template instead of default template, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Fuel's View class has an _toString() method which calls render() to render the view template. So the object returns a string when used like that.

Answer (score 0):

If the object's *result* is a string or an integer then it fits the criteria set down in the manual. Whatever is within the `exit` brackets is executed as a PHP line; see the example below:

```
$a = 4;
$b = 17;
exit(print $a * $b);
```

this will output

> 68

so, on your question:

> ```
>  exit(View::forge('error', $data));
> ```

If the returned result of `View::forge` is a string or other printable output then it fits the criteria set out by `exit` and is executed accordingly.

What will ***not*** work is a non-integer, non-string result such as:

```
$a[] = "trees";
$b[] = "cats";

exit(array_merge($a,$b));
```

Gives:

> Notice:  Array to string conversion on line 4

Due to this "conversion" I expect that if you pass an object to the `exit` function then it will probably try to use the `__toString()` class method, if available, (but I'm not certain on this yet).

Comment: thanks for your reply! I tried var_dump(View::forge('error', $data)); and it returned -> object(Fuel\Core\View)#23 () { ... etc. you mean to say the object is processed as string? and the exit() parameter will be valid?
so I don't have any problem coding this way?